# print long list in air desktop as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a long scroll-able list that has like over 800 records i wanted to print the whole list with one print job but it prints only the viewable items only here is my function:

```
function printMovieClip(clip:List) {

var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
var numPages:int = 0;
var printArea:Rectangle;
var printHeight:Number;
var printY:int = 0;

if ( printJob.start() ) {

    /* Resize movie clip to fit within page width */
    if (clip.width > printJob.pageWidth) {
        clip.width = printJob.pageWidth;
        clip.scaleY = clip.scaleX;
    }

    /* Store reference to print area in a new variable! Will save on scaling calculations later... */
    printArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, printJob.pageWidth/clip.scaleX, printJob.pageHeight/clip.scaleY);

    numPages = Math.ceil(clip.height / printJob.pageHeight);

    /* Add pages to print job */
    for (var i:int = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
        printJob.addPage(clip, printArea);
        printArea.y += printArea.height;
    }

    /* Send print job to printer */
    printJob.send();

    /* Delete job from memory */
    printJob = null;

}

}
```

Comment: why var *numPages:int = 0;* ?

Comment: well it's just a new var and this value will be changed in</br>
`numPages = Math.ceil(clip.height / printJob.pageHeight);`